# I am trying to rename a site using Set-SPSite command

Tags: 2010, powershell

I have created several host-named site collections and now I have to rename a couple.

I used the command New-SPSite to create 'http://test1.domain.com' and was able to get everything going fine, but after using Set-SPSite with the following:

Set-SPSite -Identity http://test1.domain.com -URL http://test2.domain.com

The command appears to run correctly and if I run Get-SPSite I see my new URL listed, and if I try navigating to that URL in my browser it works fine.

The problem I have though, is that I set a custom login page and set it to '~/SitePages/login.aspx' which in theory should resolve to 'http://test2.domain.com/SitePages/login.aspx' but when I try to login it's pointing me to 'http://test1.domain.com/SitePages/login.aspx'

I have the same problem with the mobile version, in that when I try to navigate to 'http://test2.domain.com' in my iPhone the browser is being redirected back to the old site URL, test1.domain.com

Is there anything after the Set-SPSite command that i need to do?  Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you set the login page previously?

Comment: ~/SitePages/login.aspx
----------------
Sorry, I misread the question I think.  I set the custom login page through central admin (I went to central admin, manage web applications, selected my web application and edited the custom login page under the authentication provider)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your custom login page a fake name and then change it back to what you had previously(~/SitePages/login.aspx). This will append the new site name(http://test2.domain.com) to your login page and replace it with the old site name(http://test2.domain.com).

Comment: Okay, I was pretty skeptical at first that this would work, but I went to central admin, manage web applications, selected my web application and edited the custom login page under the authentication provider and it worked, both the login page link and the mobile site redirect point to the correct host name (http://test2.domain.com)

Comment: Sounds like this re-writes the entry in web.config for the web application. Good to know. +1