# Change a Web Application URL

Tags: 2010, web-application

We have registered our Web Application under the url http:\intranet. We no longer wish to use that URL at all and want to use http:\somethingelse. Is there anyway you can change the default URL in SharePoint?

Comment: Have you tried changing the AAM in CA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though you can do this by modifying Alternate Access Mappings in the long run you'll be better off by deleting the old web app, but not the databases, add a new web app, activate all needed web app scoped features and attach all the old content databases.

Comment: Why would you suggest this? Why not use AAM & check the IIS bindings?

Comment: @moontear It's a tiny bit more work now, if it's a single server farm (if it's a multi server farm then I'd argue it's not more work). But if you ever want to add a new server, then you don't have to remember to change the IIS binding on the new server.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you need to use alternate access mapping for this.

Below links will get you started

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ff679917.aspx

https://support.cloudshare.com/entries/20713426-sharepoint-2010-alternate-access-mappings

Answer (score 1):

I've had to do this in the past with host-named site collections.

We used this MSDN article to get create the site collections:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288637.aspx#section1

In order to rename them afterwards you can use 'Set-SPSite' to rename them (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607958).

For example:
Set-SPSite -Identity http://test1.domain.com -URL http://test2.domain.com

I did run into one issue using this command related to the web.config file for the web app and a custom login page, but it was a pretty simple solution (http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29630/i-am-trying-to-rename-a-site-using-set-spsite-command)