# Rename SharePoint 2010 Web Server

Tags: iis, stsadm, windows-server

Can someone help me by providing the correct set of steps to rename a SharePoint 2010 Web server machine name? It's a two-server farm. Are there know issues associated with this? I've researched this and found much [conflicting](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37153/change-a-web-application-url) [info](http://www.decentrix.com/dcxblog/2011/09/01/renaming-a-server-with-sharepoint-2010/). I do not want to use alternative access mappings. It is a publishing site based Intranet.

I'm aware of the STSADM [Renameserver](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263117%28v=office.12%29.aspx) command. But what else is involved? IIS? Remove Web app? Does it break anything? etc...

Comment: Are you referring to the name of the actual server itself or the FQDN used to access the site via the web?

Comment: the name of the machine itself.

Comment: @rjcup3, totally different question and product version

Comment: @IrishChieftain, The answer provided is for 2010. The question is not exactly the same, but the answer is.

Comment: That answer does not answer my concerns here.

Answer (score 0):

For 2010 and 2013, there is the Rename-SPServer PowerShell cmdlet that will accomplish this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607556.aspx